# Conditional Binary Unpacking With Node.js

Tags: node.js, binary, conditional-statements, unpack

I have been tasked to create a node.js program which has three main components: listen for incoming data (which comes in as packed binary), unpack and parse that data, then post it to the postgreSQL database. The issue I have is that all the npm libraries node currently offers do not play nicely with conditional formats of unpacking.

The data comes in the general format:

1. A header. This piece is fixed at 20 bytes on every incoming data packet and is thus easy to parse.
2. The first information section. This has a variable length.
3. The second information section. This has a variable length.
4. The third information section. This has a variable length.

Luckily, I am given the length of each section as the first two bytes in each case.

I have a guide to tell me how long each packet of information will be within the header use the [bufferpack](https://github.com/ryanrolds/bufferpack) and [binary](https://github.com/substack/node-binary) npm libraries to parse the data as such. For the first information packet, I am not lucky enough to have a fixed guide :

```
var binary = require('binary');
var bufferpack = require('bufferpack');
//The data is received as a buffer in the main program.
exports.execute = function (data) {
    //The first piece of information is 8 bytes thus requiring
    //using binary npm. It is also big endian unsigned.
    //Bytes 0 - 7:
    var info1 = binary.parse(data).word64bu('data1').vars;
    //The next info packet is 1 unsigned byte. 
    var info2 = bufferpack.unpack('B', data, 8);
    //The next info packet is 9 bytes long, but is not collected 
    //because it is not required.

    //The last packet then is 2 bytes long, little endian unsigned
    //Bytes 18 - 19:
    var info3 = bufferpack.unpack('<H', data, 18);
    //End of header.

    //The above code runs fine and returns the expected values correctly. 

    //However, the next section of data comes in as conditional and presents
    //plenty of problems:

    //Luckily, I am given the length of the next piece of data.
    var firstSectionLength = bufferpack.unpack('<H', data, 20);
    //Next, three data packets will be sent, each containing 1-30 
    //Bytes of data. This is my current solution:
    var firstSectionInfo = bufferpack.unpack((modemInfoLength).toString() + 's', data, 22);
    //The next two information sections follow the same patter as the above.
    console.log(firstSectionInfo);
};
```

This code will log an array to the console which throws each piece of data into the first index, separated by '/u0000'. Since it is an array, I am unable to simply .split() it. However, if I .toString() the array it will return a string but deletes the '/u0000' parts leaving me with all the data strung together and no way to split them. Since they are all variable in length, I am unable to make a map to extract slices of the string as useful information.

Is there a way to either parse the data packets more effectively or parse the indexed array value reliably?

I'll add that previously python code was used to do the parsing like so:

```
def dataPacket(self, data, (host, port)):
    #I'll skip directly to how the first information section is parsed
    #...
    #Recall the header is fixed at 20 bytes.
    firstInfoSectionLength = unpack('H', data[20:22])
    firstInfoSectionBegin = 22
    firstInfoSectionEnd = firstInfoSectionBegin + firstInfoSectionLength[0]
    firstInfoSection = '%r' % data[firstInfoSectionBegin:firstInfoSectionEnd]
    firstInfoSection = firstInfoSection.strip("'")
    firstInfoSection = firstInfoSection.split('\\x00')
    data1 = firstInfoSection[0]
    data2 = firstInfoSection[1]
    data3 = firstInfoSection[2]
    data4 = firstInfoSection[3]
    data5 = firstInfoSection[4]
```

As you will notice, the python program parses the variable info length by different params then what I would be required to parse in the node.js program.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you have in `firstSectionInfo` is this:

```
['ab\u0000cd\u0000']
```

I presume you want to split the only value in the array. So you can just do:

```
['ab\u0000cd\u0000'][0].split('\u0000')
```

You'll get the values `'ab'`, `'cd'` and `''`

(By the way, you keep writing `/u0000` but this cannot correspond to Python's `\x00`.)

Comment: Unfortunately, rather than returning an array ['a','b','/u0000','c','d','/u0000'] it returns the array['ab/u0000cd/u0000'] all on the index array[0]

Comment: What are you refer to by "it" in your comment? Are you talking about the contents of `firstSectionInfo`?

Comment: Yes, the var firstSectionInfo when called to console.log will print out what I mentioned in the above comment